# Number inside circle

Tags: android

What is the best way for draw a number inside circle drawed on canvas by drawCircle?

Then this circle can be dragged by user, when circle is empty I don´t have problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will draw text centered at centerX, centerY

```
Rect rect = new Rect();

paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), rect);
float x = centerX - rect.width() / 2;
FontMetrics fm = paint.getFontMetrics();
float y= centerY - (fm.descent + fm.ascent) / 2;
canvas.drawText(text, x, y, paint);
```